# firefox:"no elememt found" error while uploading images using jquery ajax and ashx handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ashx

I am using a .ashx handler for file upload in my application...the code is working fine in chrome but in Firefox its giving a error while calling it through Ajax...

here my code..in formData I have appended images on its file input selection change

```
{           
        formData.append("type", "PropertyPhoto");

        $('#modal').css('display', 'block');
        $('#fade').css('display', 'block');
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Handler/ImageHandler.ashx',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

                AddProperty(data);

                $("#ImagesUpload").val('');
                $("#imagepreview").html('');

                $('#modal').css('display', 'none');
                $('#fade').css('display', 'none');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $('#modal').css('display', 'none');
                $('#fade').css('display', 'none');
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
```

}

Comment: what 'AddProperty(data)' function do?

Comment: that's function takes the url which is returned from the handler..

Comment: so where are you uploading images?

Comment: the code is working fine in chrome...but in firefox..its giving me error..

Comment: right now m storing it on local machine